# Message passing from external webpage to chrome addon

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a webpage send data to a chrome extension that will fire when user visit a website(say google here)

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Addon",
  "version": "0.01",
  "icons": { "16": "icon-16.ico" },

  "browser_action": {
  "default_icon" : "icon-16.ico",
  "default_popup" : "popup.html"
  },

   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.google.com/*"  ],
      "js": ["cs.js"]
    }
  ],

  "externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["*://*.mywebsite.com/*"]
}


}
```

**cs.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert("world");
  });
```

**mywebsite.com/testpage.php**

```
// The ID of my chrome extension (In developer mode)
var editorExtensionId = "cjgeckgdpfhnedenpkaanpehddchlkle";

// Send a message
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("Hello");

</script>
```

As far as i know content script have access to onMessage and sendMessage but i don't get an alert when i visit google

Comment: I think you have a conceptual misunderstanding here. Why do you expect a message from google? You will only get messages when visiting `mywebsite.com/testpage.php` because that is where the message sent from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage), the extension id should be the first parameter when calling `sendMessage()`. You simply omitted this param.
The second problem is that messages from external web page can receive only the background script.  Check the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessageExternal) for `onMessageExternal()`.
Use this code to send a message to your background extension script:

```
// The ID of my chrome extension (In developer mode)
var editorExtensionId = "cjgeckgdpfhnedenpkaanpehddchlkle";

// Send a message
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, "Hello");
```